# On Google Play there is a separate app for Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, android-app

I installed the Stack Exchange app on my Android device.

Google Play suggested I "might also like Stack Overflow". Why is there a separate app for this? Which one should I be using?

Furthermore, is this the right place to request features / report bugs for the said app(s).

Comment: Thanks for the link. As the title for that page mentions SO but not SE this is why I didn't find it in my prior search.

Comment: No problem. The decision of splitting it up makes no sense to me either. Now we have two apps with the same problems that nobody bothers to fix.